# Resize all website content on Window(width) resize

Tags: html, css, web, resize

I'm trying to figure out a way to resize all content in a webpage based on the width of the browser window. The idea is based on the website newhive, which works in this way. Here is an example:

https://newhive.com/peertospace/nargifsus?&no_paging

Using css vw alone seems to not be capable of achieving this, so i'm panning towards javascript or jquery, but with no idea where to start. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: it can be done with pure css!

Comment: Just use media queries and relative units of measurement. Google "responsive design".

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't take any steer from that website example if I were you. Everything they do on that page is horrendous from a UX point of view as well as a performance point of view. However if you really must you can use jQuery's resize function (see: https://api.jquery.com/resize/)

An example below (gets the current window width and checks if it's larger than 992px

```
function windowWidth(){
    return document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth || window.innerWidth;
}

$(window).resize(function() {
    console.log("window resize running");

    if( windowWidth() > 992){
        // do stuff
    }else{
        // do other stuff
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks. For anybody still searching for a way to do this, i found its most practical to have all content in an iframe and have the resize of jquery scale it via css